# Set a pointer returned by a function to some address C

Tags: c

I was writing some C code and I got the following problem. Suppose we have this really simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct this {
    char* str;
};

char* freeStrReturnPointer(struct this * t) {
    free(t->str);
    return t->str;
};

int main() {
    // standard mallocing going on
    struct this* t = malloc(sizeof(struct this));
    t->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    // here is the problematic part!
    freeStrReturnPointer(t) = NULL;
    // end of problematic part
    free(t);
    exit(0);
}
```

Compilation gives the following problem:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:18:29: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     freeStrReturnPointer(t) = NULL;
```

My question is: If the function freeStrReturnPointer returns a pointer char*, why can I not set it to NULL? The following would definitely work:

```
char* p;
p = NULL;
```

What is the difference here? Why can I not assign a value to the returned pointer immediately?

Caveat: I realize I can just set the pointer to null in the function, but that is not the point of the question.

Comment: You can assign to a variable, because a variable is a container. A function call just returns a value, it makes no sense to assign to it.

Comment: it doesn't matter what type it is. It's like trying to do `a + b = 3`.

Comment: Where do you expect that `NULL` to be put when you assign to the function?

Comment: `free(t->str); return t->str;` causes undefined behaviour. You may not use the value of a freed pointer

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about how C works. I suggest you read about [rvalues and lvalues](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)

Comment: I wanted the pointer s->str to point to NULL afterwards. So in this case I think I would have to return the address to the s->str pointer and then do *freeStrReturnPointer(t) = NULL;

Comment: Also, fwiw making a type named `this` is a serious source of confusion.

Comment: Imagine you have `int f() {return 5;}` - then it's the same reason you can't do `f() = 6;`

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because the expression `freeStrReturnPointer(t)` returns an r-value, which needs to be assigned to a variable in order for its lifetime to extend beyond the full expression that contains it. Assigning it to "null" literally has no visible side effects and is most likely a programmer mistake, so the language treats it as an error.

Instead you should do

```
char * p = freeStrReturnPointer(t);
p = NULL;
```

Then, in both expressions `p` is the l-value, and `freeStrReturnPointer(t)` is the r-value in the first, and `NULL` is the r-value in the second.

Alternatively, you could treat `freeStrReturnPointer(t)` as a void function and just ignore the result (since you don't use it anyways, there's no reason to set it to `NULL`):

```
(void) freeStrReturnPointer(t);
```

Comment: If you ignore the return value you should prefix the function call with `(void)` so that the compiler doesn't get angry.

Comment: even though I agree with most of your explanation, your *instead you should do* part is wrong. What you say there: `char * p = freeStrReturnPointer(t); p = NULL;`, here `p` is the rvalue that cannot have a lifetime extending beyond the expression. All you're doing by going explicit is to make the "programmer mistake" a construct that passes the error! Doing it using a `char**` is a way that will fix properly the issue, and obviously making it void and not `NULL`ing it is even better.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean to do is return a pointer to the pointer, then dereference that and set the original pointer to `NULL`.

so in your code I would write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct this {
    char* str;
};

char** freeStrReturnStrPointer(struct this * t) {
    free(t->str);
    return &t->str;
};

int main(){
    struct this* t = malloc(sizeof(struct this));
    t->str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    *freeStrReturnStrPointer(t) = NULL;
    free(t);
}
```

Which would set `str` to `NULL` after freeing it.

currently you are just returning the actual pointer to `char`, not a pointer to the storage of the pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you're trying to do is equivalent of the following:

```
char *p = freeStrReturnPointer(t); 
p = NULL;
```

which will not reset `t->str`! Your `freeStrReturnPointer()` function is returning a `char*` value that points to a string. If you assign to it, then you overwrite where it points to, making it useless code.

If you do:

```
char *p = freeStrReturnPointer(t); 
printf("%p\n", t->str);
p = NULL; 
printf("%p\n", t->str);
```

You'll get:

```
0x012345678901
0x012345678901
```

as output.

If you want to reset `t->str` you then need to use a double pointer:

```
char** freeStrReturnPointer(struct this * t) {
    free(t->str);
    return &(t->str);
};
```

and within main():

```
char **p = freeStrReturnPointer(t);
printf("%p\n", t->str);
*p = NULL;
printf("%p\n", t->str);
```

which will then output something like:

```
0x012345678901
0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

`freeStrReturnPointer()` is returning a value (right value to be more precise). In your case it's a pointer but a value nonetheless. As the compiler is telling you, you are basically trying to alter the way the `=` operator is working. Assignment operator requires a variable of some sort on the left and a value (which can again be a variable) on the right. Your problem here is not restricted to pointers. Try using even basic types or an object and you will still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the `freeStrReturnPointer(struct this * t)` what you do with `t->str` has no incidence on the variable that you created in main, and what you return is actually an rvalue (and you cannot assign something to an rvalue). I would use a pointer to pointer instead : `freeStrReturnPointer(struct this ** t)`